# Why I can't see these js errors in console

Tags: jquery, wordpress, debugging, syntax-error, flexslider

Reviewer says that there are these 2 errors in my wordpress theme. But I don't know why I can't see these errors in my browser consoles.

I've also added `define('WP_DEBUG', true); define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);` in `wp-config.php`.

These are the errors that I can't see in my console.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.flexslider-min.js:4
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'flexslider' main.js?ver=3.6:19
```

Comment: I use Crhome at the moment.

Comment: any other ideas please anyone ?  :(

Answer (score 0):

1. try another browser.
2. first open console and then If you don't see any errors try reloading the page. The error may be generated when the page loads.
3. if you using safari and If you cannot see the error click the back button within the console.

Comment: I have tried in every browser and have done everything you mentioned above lots of times before I ask question.. :(